# page "/node/add" that I would like to programmatically limit the links that are displayed based on the users role

Tags: hooks, forms

I have a page "/node/add" that I would like to programmatically limit the links that are displayed based on the users role.  Is using either hook_form_alter or hook_form_ID_alter the way to do this?
I just figured out that "/node/add" is not a form so I can't use hook_form_alter or hook_form_ID_alter but in doing a little research it appears that I may be able to user hook_page_alter() instead to filter out some of the links.

Comment: What do you mean by "link"? What are they?

Comment: The /node/add page has the following links:

"Article"

"Basic page"

"Photo Gallery"

"PR tmp"

"Webform"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set node creation permission (Node Module on `www.yourhost.com/admin/user/permissions`) to specific roles, the existing form should take care of this automagically by itself, eg, if the user accessing `www.yourhost.com/node/add` can't create a specific node type, it won't be presented on that page.

Based upon commentary, `node/add` is built via:

```
function node_add_page() {
  $item = menu_get_item();
  $content = system_admin_menu_block($item);
  return theme('node_add_list', $content);
}   

/** 
 * Display the list of available node types for node creation.
 *  
 * @ingroup themeable
 */ 
function theme_node_add_list($content) {
  $output = '';

  if ($content) {
    $output = '<dl class="node-type-list">';
    foreach ($content as $item) {
      $output .= '<dt>'. l($item['title'], $item['href'], $item['localized_options']) .'</dt>';
      $output .= '<dd>'. filter_xss_admin($item['description']) .'</dd>';
    }
    $output .= '</dl>';
  } 
  return $output;
}
```

so you most certainly could create a new `YOURTHEME_node_add_list()` function that filters the links based upon a user's role realizing that if the user entered the link directly it would nonetheless still work.

You could also create a `node-add-list.tpl.php` in your theme's directory with basically this in it as a start:

```
<?php

  $output='';

  if ($content) {
    $output = '<dl class="node-type-list lrfm-ed">';
    foreach ($content as $item) {
      $output .= '<dt>'. l($item['title'], $item['href'], $item['localized_options']) .'</dt>';
      $output .= '<dd>'. filter_xss_admin($item['description']) .'</dd>';
    }
    $output .= '</dl>';
  } 
  print $output;
```

and then modify it however you wanted.

Just flush caches after either to make drupal's theme system see and pick up the changes.

Comment: I am aware about limiting access to content types by role but the problem is that I can't get the workbench module to work correctly unless I give the access "Node: Bypass content access control" to users that use workbench/workflow which causes all the content types to be listed within /node/add page.

Comment: This YOURTHEME_node_add_list() function do I put this within a custom module like to do for hooks?

Comment: it would go inside your theme, most usually template.php

Comment: you could also create a `node-add-list.tpl.php` file with the logic in it and save that in your theme's directory if you didn't want to modify any files there directly.  (inside of which you would basically just print $output instead of returning it)

Comment: (and remember to clear your caches after doing either)

Comment: I cleared my caches both (drupal and varnish) and it does not seem to be processing my new function Mytheme_node_add_list($content)

Comment: I pulled out Drupal 6 direct examples, if you are running D7 it is slightly different, but should also be giving you an error if it is being called.  the function should be the precise theme name you are using followed by _node_add_list(...).